QGIS Batch processing for minimum bounding geometry?
I wouldn't call myself a QGIS "expert" so I'm asking for any recommendations/solutions.
During a project I've collected individual animal locations in a zoological institution in 10 min intervals. So every giraffe, gemsbok etc. gets their location marked from different observation points. Now I want to analyse how big the size of each species group is during each observation interval (in terms of area). I want to use minimum bounding geometry to do this.
Since I have a lot of observation intervals I wanted to make this more efficient with batch processing, but I am stuck at this point.
Example table



date
intervall
species




30.09
09:30
giraffe (1)


30.09
09:30
giraffe (2)


30.09
09:30
giraffe (3)


30.09
09.30
gemsbok (1)


30.09
09:30
gemsbok (2)


30.09
09:30
gemsbok (3)


01.10
10:30
giraffe (1)


01.10
10:30
giraffe (2)


01.10
10:30
giraffe (3)


01.10
10:30
waterbuck (1)


01.10
10:30
waterbuck (1)



.....etc.
I want to have minimum bounding geometries for each species group at each intervall and date.
Is there a way to to batch process this and not to filter everything tediously by hand? And additionally to have all the data in one combined table?

Start with Dissolve

You can also create a unique key per group and use it in the tool. It could be simply a concatenation of the 3 fields.

Simple but effective.. Thanks for that input. WORKED

@JGH can you post an answer so OP can accept it and the question can be "closed out"

Start with Dissolve
You can also create a unique key per group and use it in the tool. It could be simply a concatenation of the 3 fields.
